# Can't find file 'com.facebook.android.facebook' on Facebook SDK Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hello I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK for my Android app and every tutorial I'm looking at is telling me different things and using

`Facebook fb = new Facebook(appID);`

I dont have that "Facebook.java" in my Facebook SDk, I do have files like FacebookActivity.java and stuff. All those tutorials I'm looking at were made in like 2012 (we're in 2015), was the SDK updated and changed since then and now its different codes and files? Can someone tell me how I go about doing the same task or what am I supposed to be doing please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed and updated tutorial by Facebook to add Facebook SDK in your application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: I tried following that but I'm trying to make a photo app and enabled to share the photo to facebook. I tried following the photo sharing tutorial on the facebook website but it had me confused. its sometimes easier to actually see someone doing it or an actual example with the code

Comment: Your question was about SDK.